# Transform unicode string in python

Tags: python, unicode, dictionary

```
{u'Status': u'OK', u'City': u'Ciri\xe8', u'TimezoneName': '', u'ZipPostalCode': '', u'CountryCode': u'IT', u'Dstoffset': u'0', u'Ip': u'x.x.x.x', u'Longitude': u'7.6', u'CountryName': u'Italy', u'RegionCode': u'12', u'Latitude': u'45.2333', u'Isdst': '', u'Gmtoffset': u'0', u'RegionName': u'Piemonte'}
```

This is the output of my object. I would like to access City but It's encoded. How can I read all parameters and decode it

```
>>> data['City']
u'Ciri\xe8'

>>>data['City'].decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe8' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I want plaintext not unicode string. Thank you!

Comment: I'm using this code https://github.com/sonicrules1234/pyipinfodb/blob/master/pyipinfodb.py

Comment: There is no such thing as "plaintext".

Comment: You don't have to do anything. It's already decoded... Try `print data['City']`

Comment: As you see in the post the result of print data['City'] is u'Ciri\xe8'

Comment: No, you just typed `data['City']`. Try `print data['City']`. For me, in iPython, that makes a difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read this: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Then just print it:

```
>>> data = {u'City':u'Ciri\xe8'}
>>> data['City']
u'Ciri\xe8'
>>> print data['City']
Ciriè
```

If you don't print it, Python prints a safe representation of the string, indicating it is Unicode text `u''`, and that it contains a non-ASCII character `\xe8`.  `print` attempts to display the non-ASCII character by encoding the Unicode string in the terminal encoding.  It may fail if the string contains characters that aren't supported by the terminal encoding:

```
>>> print u'\xe8'
è
>>> print u'\x81'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "d:\dev\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\x81' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

In the above example, [code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) supports Unicode character U+00E8, but not U+0081.

Answer (score 9):

What you want is not clear. If by 'plaintext' you mean remove accentuation, try this:

```
>>> s = u'Ciri\xe8'
>>> from unicodedata import normalize
>>> normalize('NFKD', s).encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
'Cirie'
```

Answer (score 0):

By plaintext, I suppose you mean ascii.  For this you can use:

```
data['City'].encode('ascii','ignore')
```

this will strip the unicode character and return

```
Ciri
```

See this link for more information: http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html