# UTF-32 in Python

Tags: python, unicode

I cannot display theunicode item `u'\u201d'`. I didn't have problems with other unicode items. I used UTF-8, but then this character shows up and rained hell on my code. I tried different things in the interpreter. But basically where:

```
c = u'\u201d'
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#154>", line 1, in <module>
    c.decode('utf-32')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_32.py", line 11, in decode
    return codecs.utf_32_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201d' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I need to display it in the GUI so I can check the output and then store it as plain text.
[Transform unicode string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264618/transform-unicode-string-in-python)
explains a bit, however I am still clearly missing something.

Comment: What is c in c.decode('utf-32')?

Comment: the value i mentioned u'\u201d'

Comment: So this question is an exact duplicate of the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545843/unicode-error-ordinal-not-in-range asked by yourself 2 hours ago.

Comment: yes a person in comments said it got off topic and asked for reposting.... i am fairly frustrated with this right now so i ended up doing it, once i resolve the issue i will delete least useful one

Comment: You haven't defined what you mean by "GUI" and you haven't told us which OS+application is going to open the resulting text file. They both make a difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're getting this exception, then you're trying to call `.decode()` on a unicode string. You should only call `.decode()` on a byte string, and only call `.encode()` on a unicode string. Otherwise, the interpreter will first implicitly encode or decode the string using the default codec (usually 'ascii'), which is bad news.

In general, I recommend reading http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/ carefully...

Comment: If I encode   u'\u201d'.encode('utf-32') I get:
'\xff\xfe\x00\x00\x1d \x00\x00'
I need to convert that symbol into plain text for GUI and save it as txt

Comment: define “plain text”. There is no such thing as “plain text” in that context. I suggest reading [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: i've read that file, it is useful but I am still confused how to go about my problem. All I need is to convert anything that is not human readable into readable format so I can test it for certain conditions and then write it to a file. I am not a professional coder in any sense. I simply need clean output, thats all

Answer (score 2):

If you had read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) you would know **There Ain't No Such Thing As Plain Text**..

But since there doesn't seem to be a meeting of the minds between what you insist you're after and what people are trying to explain, I'm starting to wonder if by "convert that symbol into plain text" you mean something like "replace the Unicode RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK (U+201D) with QUOTATION MARK (U+0022) and then encode as ASCII".  For example, something like:

```
In [45]: s = u"“curly quoted”"

In [46]: s
Out[46]: u'\u201ccurly quoted\u201d'

In [47]: print s
“curly quoted”
```

and then doing the replacements manually (search for "unicode string sanitize" and you'll find much better recipes including more "downgrades" for different characters):

```
In [51]: fixer = dict.fromkeys([0x201c, 0x201d], u'"')

In [52]: s.translate(fixer)
Out[52]: u'"curly quoted"'

In [53]: s.translate(fixer).encode("ascii", "replace")
Out[53]: '"curly quoted"'
```

where the "replace" would protect against anything we didn't fix.