# Python Pandas to_csv Output Returns Single Character for String/Object Values

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, unicode, pyodbc, vertica

I'm attempting to output the result into a pandas data frame. When I print the data frame, the object values appear correct, but when I use the to_csv function on the data frame, my csv output has only the first character for every string/object value.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'a':[u'u\x00s\x00']})
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

I've also tried the following addition to the to_csv function:

```
df.to_csv('test_encoded.csv', encoding= 'utf-8')
```

But am getting the same results:

```
>>> print df
      a
0  us

(output in csv file)
u
```

For reference, I'm connecting to a Vertica database and using the following setup:

- OS: Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10.5)
- Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, Sep 15 2015,
  14:29:08)
- pyodbc 3.0.10
- pandas 0.16.2
- ODBC: Vertica ODBC 6.1.3

Any help figuring out how to pass the entire object string using the to_csv function in pandas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This can be replicated with `df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[u'u\x00s\x00']})`, `df.to_csv()` (the sql part does not really matter)

Comment: thanks @joris - I've updated the question to simplify it and reflect the core issue

Comment: The backslashes in the unicode string need to be escaped.  `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [u'u\\x00s\\x00']})` returns a dataframe with the `u\x00s\x00` written out properly.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and found this post [UTF-32 in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546705/utf-32-in-python)

To fix your problem, I believe that you need to replace all '**\x00**' by **empty**. I managed to write the correct CSV with the code below

```
fixer = dict.fromkeys([0x00], u'')
df['a'] = df['a'].map(lambda x: x.translate(fixer))
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

To solve my problem with Vertica I had to change the encoding to **UTF-16** in the file **/Library/Vertica/ODBC/lib/vertica.ini** with the configuration below

```
[Driver]
ErrorMessagesPath=/Library/Vertica/ODBC/messages/
ODBCInstLib=/usr/lib/libiodbcinst.dylib
DriverManagerEncoding=UTF-16
```

Best regards,
Anderson Neves