# Save pandas dataframe into csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a problem in saving large panda dataframe into the csv file.
below is just snapshot of first 3 lines of panda dataframes.

```
              parent_sernum                    parent_pid            created_date                                             sernum                                                pid                                                 pn
 0   FCH21467XBN      UXXXX-XXX-XXXX 2017-12-20 11:02:00.177  SSGQA20741370EA85A,SSGQA...  UXXXX, 22RV-A,Uxxx-xx...  15-104065-01,15-104065-0...
 1   FCH21467XBN      Uxxxx-xxx-xx 2017-12-20 11:38:45.373  SSGQA20741370EA85A,SSGQA...  Uxx-xxx-xxxx-A,Uxx-xx-...  15-104065-01,15-104065-0...
 2   FCH2145V0UW    Uxxx-xxxx-M4S 2017-12-02 11:01:26.993  SSH8A2071935A2ACDE,SSH8A...  Uxx-xx-1X324RV-A,UCS-ML-...  15-104064-01,15-104064-0...
```

When it comes to save this dataframe into csv file. it only captures First letter and drops the rest from most of columns as below.

```
  parent_sernum,parent_pid,created_date,sernum,pid,pn
  F,U,2017-12-20 11:02:00.177,S,U,1
  F,U,2017-12-20 11:38:45.373,S,U,1
  F,U,2017-12-02 11:01:26.993,S,U,1
```

Below is my codes when it comes to save data. (df = dataframe).
Is there any option that I need to set if I need to save all from dataframe?
Or is there a limitation in csv file size so it automatically captures only fraction of data to meet the size restriction?

```
 df.to_csv('sample.csv', index = False, header = True)
```

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: Do you mean python version ? , it is Python 2.7.5.

Comment: pandas version. Check with `pd.__version__`

Comment: >>> pd.__version__
u'0.21.1'

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem based on your question.

Comment: You may benefit from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703664/python-pandas-to-csv-output-returns-single-character-for-string-object-values

Comment: this works, thanks so much!